# This is probably a regular expression issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is what I have:

```
 $fullvalue = "Mario characters Mario Luigi Toad Peach Bowser## Mario characters";

 $leftpound = preg_replace("/(## )+(.)$/","", $fullvalue);

 $rightpound = preg_replace("/^(.)+(## )/","", $fullvale);

 $addition = "Toadette Koopa Wario Daisy";

 $composite = $leftpound . " " . $addition . "## " . $rightpound;
```

The point of all this is that the "title" of this row can be displayed with $rightpound and the keywords for a search function are written into the same line. My problem is that the preg_replace in $leftpound isn't replacing anything. Did I do something I'm not supposed to? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in your pattern : **(.)$** is waiting for a single caracter at the end of the string

You have to change it with : **(.)+$**

You can test regex online : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you both. Silly mistake on my part. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's becouse of `$` in your expression it means the text should be end(finish)

```
$leftpound = preg_replace("/(## )+(.)/","", $fullvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
$composite = preg_replace("/(## )/", " $addition$1 ", $fullvalue);
```